# my webapp can not find beans in context.xml

Tags: java, xml, spring, hibernate

SOLVED!!!
I moved context.xml into web-inf folder and changed context-param to this:

```
<context-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/context.xml</param-value>
        </context-param>
```

"No qualifying bean of type [org.hibernate.SessionFactory] found for dependency.." exception I'm getting when I'm trying to save my class User into database. Dao class:

```
@Repository
public class UserDaoImpl extends HibernateDaoSupport implements UserDao {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public void addUser(User user) {
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(user);
    }

}
```

my bean definitions are here: resources/context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/db</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.username">user</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.password">pw</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>com.wily.User</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Can You pls tell  me what I'm doing wrong? thx.

EDIT:web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
                        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
                        version="3.0">

    <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml, classpath:context.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

</web-app>
```

-again, context.xml is in resources folder

Comment: Is this a standalone application or is it running as part of a webapp? How do you initialize the Spring container?

Comment: its part of webapp, and the problem seems to be that I don't know how to initialize the container, can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize the Spring container on application start-up. You can do so in your web.xml as below. Assuming you are also using Spring MVC, best practice is keep MVC config separate from the rest of your config.

I would also recommend using the new JPA standard based approach (using EntityManager) to setting all this up rather than the old mechanism.

**Example Spring Configuration:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="jpaAdapter"></property>
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="persistenceUnit" />
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${hibernate.ddl.auto}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show.sql}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">${hibernate.enable.cache}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="jpaAdapter"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />

    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager"
        id="transactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

**Example Spring Datasource Definition**

http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd">

```
<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName">
        <value>${database.driver}</value>
    </property>
    <property name="url">
        <value>${database.url}</value>
    </property>
    <property name="username">
        <value>${database.username}</value>
    </property>
    <property name="password">
        <value>${database.password}</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

**Minimal Persisteance.XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="2.0"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="persistenceUnit"
        transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy" value="org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.charSet" value="UTF-8" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

**Example Repository Class**

```
@Repository
public ExampleRepository{

@PersistenceContext
private Entitymanager;

}
```

**Example web.xml**

```
xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0">
    <display-name>My Web Application</display-name>

    <!-- INIT DISPATCHER SERVLET : POINT TO SPRING CONFIG CONTAINING ONLY MVC MAPPINGS -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContextServlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>


    <!-- DEFINE THE LOCATION OF ALL NON-MVC SPRING CONFIG-->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            classpath:applicationContext1.xml,
            classpath:applicationContext2.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- DEFINE LISTENER TO INITIALIZE ALL NON-MVC SPRING CONFIG -->
    <listener>
       <listener-class>
          org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
       </listener-class>
    </listener>

</web-app>
```

Comment: i updated topic with web.xml file im using, the problem keeps.